# Drupal 7 Draggable Views in different order when logged in

Tags: views

My site is : www.terrafirmasouth.co.uk
I have draggable views set up for projects, I have a menu option called 'Sort Projects', certain users can access this to rearrange projects, if they have a role called 'publisher' . 
I have given the Publisher role access to 'Sort Draggable Views' in People/Permissions (but not for anonymous users). When they are logged in, they can rearrange projects under a Sort Projects menu item (path is 'sort-projects'), and the order seems fine, then when they log out the order just reverts back to what it was before the update. When they log back in again, the order to retained from the previous update.  When I log in as administrator and do the same thing i.e. change order of a project,  the order is fine , and when I log out.

Is there some other permission I need to set for anonymous users so they see they updated order? Also, on the Sort Projects screen, it doesnt show 'updated successfully or saved' in green  at the top which I would normally expect, i dont get any message, other than the spinning circle at the top, then it finishes as normal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved by following this link:- 
http://drupal.org/node/616658

Scroll to the bottom, and follow instructions in the last Post whereby you install the Rule module, create a rule to clear cache on sorting a View, you may have a problem where the option to create custom PHP is not in the drop down list, if so, this is resolved by enabling the 'PHP Filter' module.

All tested and works perfectly ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Draggable views doesn't suits you.

You have to create your own views handler to allow each user to have it's own elements order.

Comment: Hi @OlegSherbakov , thanks for response. Bit lost with that, can you be more specific? I only have 1 user that needs to do this, plus me as admin? The problem seems to be related to cache (Its referenced here : http://drupal.org/node/283498 under 'what to be aware of'), if I untick all the Cache boxes in Performance, then it works fine, the solution seems to be to install the cacheexclude module to add the 'sort-projects' path which does the reordering for my projects - or is there a better way ?

Comment: installing and setting cacheexclude didnt work , so might try content cache.